# Why python code cannot connect to RabbitMQ remotely?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, remote-access

I'm trying to connect from the one machine to another remote server with installed RabbitMQ.
The RabbitMQ is working perfectly locally, but when I connect to it from the another machine then an error is occurs:

```
root@xxx:~# python3 rabbitmq.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rabbitmq.py", line 8, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(parameters))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 652, in __init__
    self.host = host
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 392, in host
    (value,))
TypeError: host must be a str or unicode str, but got <ConnectionParameters host=111.111.111.111 port=5672 virtual_host=product ssl=False>
root@xxx:~#
```

> **TypeError: host must be a str or unicode str, but got ConnectionParameters host=111.111.111.111 port=5672
>   virtual_host=product ssl=False**

The Python code on other remote machine:

```
import pika
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username='remoteuser', password='mypassword')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='111.111.111.111', port=5672, virtual_host='/', credentials=credentials)
#connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('111.111.111.111:15672')) # --- it doesn't work too
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(parameters))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

User "remoteuser" has admin rights and access to virtual host "/"

http://111.111.111.111:15672/#/users

```
Name        Tags            Can access virtual hosts    Has password
remoteuser  administrator   /                               ●
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have double wrapped `parameters`, change:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(parameters))
```

to:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
```

Comment: glad to help out.

Comment: After that, if you get the error: `pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError` then, make sure that you have installed RabbitMQ on your computer.